# Understanding function with string validation

Tags: ios, swift

Consider following:

```
extension String {

    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
         print(characterset)
        if self.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
            return false
        }   else {
            return true
        }

    }
}

var name = "Login"
name.isValidEmail() // print true
var incorretLogin = "Loginъ"
incorretLogin.isValidEmail() // print false
```

Yes, function is work. But im in confussion - how its work?
If i understand correct it work like that:
it take set of characters, then check if all of tested string characters contain symbols from set, and if it is not, then it return false.

Ok, but what is inverted for? If i remove inverted, result will be wrong:

```
var name = "Login"
name.isValidEmail() // false
var incorretLogin = "Logъin"
incorretLogin.isValidEmail() // false
```

Now i understand nothing.
If function check simply if string letters are from character set, then why is it matter if set inverted or not?
Could someone explain?

I play a bit in playground:

```
 let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "a")
        print(characterset)
        print(characterset.inverted)
```

Print same result:

```
<CFCharacterSet Items(U+0061)>
<CFCharacterSet Items(U+0061)>
```

Comment: Actually what are you calling **inverted** ?? I mean for what you using **inverted** word??

Comment: @dahiya_boy i took code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703039/check-if-string-contains-special-characters-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inverted` "returns an inverted copy of the receiver." (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset).

In your case `inverted` means all the characters **except** the ones you provide in the initializer (all characters except letters and digits). So the method returns `false` if the email string contains any character that is **not** a letter or a digit.

Playground example:
[image: playground example]

Comment: Please check my updated question. I check results for inverted and not, results the same, why?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban See my playground example. As you can see on the right they are different sets. While the "original" set contains the character **a** the inverted set does **not**. Instead it contains all characters **except** of the character **a**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> ```
> rangeOfCharacter(from:)
> ```
>
> Finds and returns the range in the receiver of the first character from a given character set.

The receiver is the string being checked. When no character from the set is found in the string, `nil` is returned.

When the set is inverted, it contains all *invalid* characters. Hence, `rangeOfCharacter(from:)` returns the location of the first invalid character. That is why your first approach works.

When you remove `inverted`, the call returns the location of the first *valid* character. Since `"Logъin"` has both valid and invalid characters, both calls return `false`. If you call your second function on a string consisting entirely of invalid characters, e.g. `"Логин"`, you would get `true`.

Note that you can simplify the implementation by removing `if`:

```
let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) == nil
```

Comment: thanks  but please take a look at my updated question below. How do you explain that? Both inverted or not set print same result.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I think it's just a printing artifact of inverted set - iOS prints it as if it were not inverted.

Comment: so you say it's just print error, and it "suppose" to containt all possible letter except "a"?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Yes, I tried a few more combinations, and this is what it looks like to me.